# How to erase the statusbar in mobile Safari while beeing in a fullscreen WebApp in horizontal Mode?

Tags: html, css, iphone, web-applications, safari

I'm currently working on a mobile WebApp for iOS. The User Bookmarks the App to his homescreen - the app is apple-mobile-web-app-capable, so the fullscreen mode works just fine. The statusbar is visible on top, which is fine too.

When the iPhone is rotated and in landscape mode, the status bar is NOT shown, but there is a white bar at its place, wasting space. This white bar is exactly as high as the statusbar.

I already played around with the meta-tags, without any success.

```
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
```

I either want to remove the 'empty' status bar or just show it in landscape mode.